# How to get Excel to show username of person that has file open?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, network-shares, read-only

When our admin staff try to open an Excel document on a shared network drive that someone already has open, they get the following message. The name shown (under the red box in the snapshot) is not the username of the person logged in, and so is totally unhelpful to know who has the file open as it is the same for every user.

I know that I have seen the message say a username before but don't know how get this to happen.

Where is Excel getting the name that it shows from, and how can I get Excel to show the username of who has it open??

[image: File in use message]

PS. I am aware that there is a way to enable multi-user editing in Excel but I don't want to enable this option due to the threat of data corruption.

Comment: Its doubtful you will be able to make this change unless you are one of those admin staff yourself.

Comment: I'm the administrator, I can either change whatever needs to be changed to get it to show the names, or ask the admin staff to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found it, in Excel 2010, File-Options. The name shown comes from where the red box is in this snapshot:

[image]

Seems I will have to run around and get everyone to change the name in their options.

Answer (score 0):

If the person who has the file open has an account on your computer then your computer can identify them via the SID.

If the person who has the file open is unknown to your computer, then it will know nothing more than the SID, which does not help.

If your computers are all part of an Active Directory domain, then each workstation knows how to ask the domain controller for the identity of the user who has the SID.

Comment: They are all on an Active Directory domain. How do I view the SID of whoever has the file open?